# Measuring distance with IR laser sensor Nexus 6P and 5X

Tags: android, distance, sensors

Is there a possibility to measuring distance with the build in IR laser sensor?

Answer (score 0):

According to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus6P/comments/433fg7/can_you_use_the_laser_from_the_autofocus_on_the/), most of camera apps append a "distance" field to the exif suppliment. So your task is:

1. Take a picture
2. Upload it to http://regex.info/exif.cgi
3. Parse the result, extract the distance

Comment: Not every, most. I think it should be "some". It's hard to find one